# can a server accept connection from another subnet?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

[image]

A socket server runs on 'subnet a', which initialize with `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)`.
is there an option for this socket make it possible for server to accept connection from 'subnet b'(I have no access to configure router)?

Comment: This depends on how the routers are configured. If the routing is sane and there are no prohibiting firewall rules in place, the connections should succeed; this is what routers (and routing) are for.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://serverfault.com/questions/21605/getting-2-different-local-subnets-to-see-each-other

Comment: OH! I forget to describe that router is totally sane. this server is a part of a very old c/c++ project. I need to rebuild it to achieve that.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I can't configure other devices but rebuild this server... so, in other words, how to implement a socket server can handle client requests from another subnet in c/c++.

Comment: It's about the bind-address. If it is INADDR_ANY, the server will accept connections from any subnet it is connected to, and from any other subnet that has a route into any of these subnets. If it isn't, it will only accept connections from the specified subnet and any other subnets that have a route into it.